# vertical javascript infinite text carousel with variable sized elements

Tags: javascript, text, resize, jcarousel

I have a series of testimonials to display in a sidebar. I have them working fine with jCarousel, but the client wants to be able to put in varying amounts of text for each testimonial. It looks very ugly when only part of the last testimonial is displayed.

jCarousel does allow you to apply things to non-visible items, but unfortunately the item counts as visible whether part or all of it is in view. If there's some reliable way of hiding any partially visible items, that would be acceptable.

An alternative is to make all testimonials a static height (which is, say, 1/3rd of the total height), but this causes large spaces in-between each element, and looks ugly on the shorter ones.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this situation work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example :
http://jsfiddle.net/HxKAJ/

Heights are variable, and I'm fading the font color of partially visible items, but you can hide those if you want,  like this:

```
.v-carousel-mask li {visibility:hidden}
.v-carousel-mask .visible-carousel-item {visibility:visible}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's absolutely brilliant! It's perfect for my needs.